# How do i access the object "quote" in this case

Tags: javascript, json

```
let obj = {
   "data":{
      "1":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"Bitcoin",
         "symbol":"BTC",
         "slug":"bitcoin",
         "num_market_pairs":9547,
         "date_added":"2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
         "tags":[
            "mineable",
            "pow",
            "sha-256",
            "store-of-value",
            "state-channels",
            "coinbase-ventures-portfolio",
            "three-arrows-capital-portfolio",
            "polychain-capital-portfolio",
            "binance-labs-portfolio",
            "arrington-xrp-capital",
            "blockchain-capital-portfolio",
            "boostvc-portfolio",
            "cms-holdings-portfolio",
            "dcg-portfolio",
            "dragonfly-capital-portfolio",
            "electric-capital-portfolio",
            "fabric-ventures-portfolio",
            "framework-ventures",
            "galaxy-digital-portfolio",
            "huobi-capital",
            "alameda-research-portfolio",
            "a16z-portfolio",
            "1confirmation-portfolio",
            "winklevoss-capital",
            "usv-portfolio",
            "placeholder-ventures-portfolio",
            "pantera-capital-portfolio",
            "multicoin-capital-portfolio",
            "paradigm-xzy-screener"
         ],
         "max_supply":21000000,
         "circulating_supply":18692506,
         "total_supply":18692506,
         "is_active":1,
         "cmc_rank":1,
         "is_fiat":0,
         "last_updated":"2021-04-27T09:22:02.000Z",
         "quote":{
            "1":{
               "price":1,
               "volume_24h":965406.9661335326,
               "percent_change_1h":0,
               "percent_change_24h":0,
               "percent_change_7d":0,
               "market_cap":18692506,
               "last_updated":"2021-04-27T09:22:02.000Z"
            },
            "2781":{
               "price":54568.7924803267,
               "volume_24h":52681092394.002525,
               "percent_change_1h":-0.34304915,
               "percent_change_24h":3.79062581,
               "percent_change_7d":-0.32627555,
               "market_cap":1020027480851.2617,
               "last_updated":"2021-04-27T09:22:10.000Z"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

how do i access the "quote" object here. whenever i try to access by obj.data.1.quote it returns an error stating that an unexpected number was found. I dont see any other way of accessing this object.I tried using an index but it returns undefined. Im not really sure on how i can access this object and it would be helpful if someone could help me.

Comment: `obj.data[1].quote`

Comment: Here is the documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#dot_notation

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```js
let obj = {
   "data":{
      "1":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"Bitcoin",
         "symbol":"BTC",
         "slug":"bitcoin",
         "num_market_pairs":9547,
         "date_added":"2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
         "tags":[
            "mineable",
            "pow",
            "sha-256",
            "store-of-value",
            "state-channels",
            "coinbase-ventures-portfolio",
            "three-arrows-capital-portfolio",
            "polychain-capital-portfolio",
            "binance-labs-portfolio",
            "arrington-xrp-capital",
            "blockchain-capital-portfolio",
            "boostvc-portfolio",
            "cms-holdings-portfolio",
            "dcg-portfolio",
            "dragonfly-capital-portfolio",
            "electric-capital-portfolio",
            "fabric-ventures-portfolio",
            "framework-ventures",
            "galaxy-digital-portfolio",
            "huobi-capital",
            "alameda-research-portfolio",
            "a16z-portfolio",
            "1confirmation-portfolio",
            "winklevoss-capital",
            "usv-portfolio",
            "placeholder-ventures-portfolio",
            "pantera-capital-portfolio",
            "multicoin-capital-portfolio",
            "paradigm-xzy-screener"
         ],
         "max_supply":21000000,
         "circulating_supply":18692506,
         "total_supply":18692506,
         "is_active":1,
         "cmc_rank":1,
         "is_fiat":0,
         "last_updated":"2021-04-27T09:22:02.000Z",
         "quote":{
            "1":{
               "price":1,
               "volume_24h":965406.9661335326,
               "percent_change_1h":0,
               "percent_change_24h":0,
               "percent_change_7d":0,
               "market_cap":18692506,
               "last_updated":"2021-04-27T09:22:02.000Z"
            },
            "2781":{
               "price":54568.7924803267,
               "volume_24h":52681092394.002525,
               "percent_change_1h":-0.34304915,
               "percent_change_24h":3.79062581,
               "percent_change_7d":-0.32627555,
               "market_cap":1020027480851.2617,
               "last_updated":"2021-04-27T09:22:10.000Z"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

console.log( obj.data["1"].quote )
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
       let obj = {
   "data":{
      "1":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"Bitcoin",
         "symbol":"BTC",
         "slug":"bitcoin",
         "num_market_pairs":9547,
         "date_added":"2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
         "tags":[
            "mineable",
            "pow",
            "sha-256",
            "store-of-value",
            "state-channels",
            "coinbase-ventures-portfolio",
            "three-arrows-capital-portfolio",
            "polychain-capital-portfolio",
            "binance-labs-portfolio",
            "arrington-xrp-capital",
            "blockchain-capital-portfolio",
            "boostvc-portfolio",
            "cms-holdings-portfolio",
            "dcg-portfolio",
            "dragonfly-capital-portfolio",
            "electric-capital-portfolio",
            "fabric-ventures-portfolio",
            "framework-ventures",
            "galaxy-digital-portfolio",
            "huobi-capital",
            "alameda-research-portfolio",
            "a16z-portfolio",
            "1confirmation-portfolio",
            "winklevoss-capital",
            "usv-portfolio",
            "placeholder-ventures-portfolio",
            "pantera-capital-portfolio",
            "multicoin-capital-portfolio",
            "paradigm-xzy-screener"
         ],
         "max_supply":21000000,
         "circulating_supply":18692506,
         "total_supply":18692506,
         "is_active":1,
         "cmc_rank":1,
         "is_fiat":0,
         "last_updated":"2021-04-27T09:22:02.000Z",
         "quote":{
            "1":{
               "price":1,
               "volume_24h":965406.9661335326,
               "percent_change_1h":0,
               "percent_change_24h":0,
               "percent_change_7d":0,
               "market_cap":18692506,
               "last_updated":"2021-04-27T09:22:02.000Z"
            },
            "2781":{
               "price":54568.7924803267,
               "volume_24h":52681092394.002525,
               "percent_change_1h":-0.34304915,
               "percent_change_24h":3.79062581,
               "percent_change_7d":-0.32627555,
               "market_cap":1020027480851.2617,
               "last_updated":"2021-04-27T09:22:10.000Z"
            }
         }
      }
   }
        }
        var name = obj.data[1].name;
        console.log(name);
```

try this it should work fine